# Recursively sorting two separate lists

Tags: python, sorting, recursion

Define a recursive function named `sort`; it is passed any unordered list; it returns a new list (not mutating the argument) that contains every value in the argument list, but in non-descending order.

For example, calling `sort([4,5,3,1,6,7,2])` would call sort recursively on the lists `[4,5,3]`and `[1,6,7,2]`, returning the lists `[3,4,5]` and `[1,2,6,7]` respectively, which when merged would be return the list `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`.

Note when the length of the list is even, both sublists will have the same 
size; when the length of the list is odd, it is natural to divide it into two lists, the first of which has one fewer values than the second.

The function starts like this:

```
def sort(l):
```

I know how to separate l into two list, for example `[4,5,3,1,6,7,2]`, I separate them into `[4,5,3]` and `[1,6,7,2]`. But I really don't know how to recursively sorting each half when the sort function only has one argument l.

Can someone please tell the way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: You should google for Quicksort/Mergesort

Comment: Your homework says "calling `sort([4,5,3,1,6,7,2])` would call `sort` recursively on the lists `[4,5,3]` and `[1,6,7,2]`".  What part is confusing?

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a go and it seems to work. Like TobiasR said, it's a merge sort. If you want a better explanation of how it works, I'd check out [this video on merge sorts by Harvard University](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EeQ8pwjQxTM).
Anyway, this is the code for it:

```
def sort(l):
    if len(l)==2:
        if l[0]<l[1]:
            return l #return list as it is
        return l[::-1] #return reversed list
    elif len(l)==1:
        return l
    l_1=sort(l[:len(l)//2]) # cut the list in half
    l_2=sort(l[len(l)//2:])
    l_out=[]
    while True:
        if not l_1: #check l1 isn't empty
            l_out+=l_2
            break;
        elif not l_2: #check l2 isn't empty
            l_out+=l_1
            break;
        if l_1[0]<l_2[0]: #put the smallest item in the list
            l_out.append(l_1.pop(0))
        else:
            l_out.append(l_2.pop(0))
    return l_out
```